# Regex извлечь последний элемент в найденной строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть исходные данные:

- 2011.12.17
- DevType(ID)     4            280
- 3470-52T-AC

Необходимо осуществить поиск строки где находиться слово DevType - это мы делаем так `DevType.+`

Далее из найденной этой строки нужно извлечь число 280. Как пример если у нас только нужная строка `\s\w+$`

По отдельности это легко сделать, но вот как одним запросом сделать ?

Comment: собственно сложить их вместе `DevType.*\s(\w+)$` https://regex101.com/r/HSFSAT/1 число забирать из первой группы захвата. Или \K перед ней поставить, что бы левая часть как бы не попадала в выражение, если ваш диалект регулярок это позволяет

Comment: @Mike написано что в исходных данных не одна строка. Есть еще 2

Comment: Т.е. это один большой текст ? А что если в нем несколько DevType то нужно только один, первый?, последний? или каждый по очереди ?  С модификатором 'm' выражения (multiline) понижаем жадность захвата строки добавив вопрос `DevType.*?\s(\w+)$` , https://regex101.com/r/HSFSAT/2

Comment: @Mike тут 3 строки повторюсь. DevType только один

Comment: ok. Я дал ссылку на пример с 3 строками и первая группа захвата с приведенным выражением дает именно 280. что еще не так ? вот для надежности прямо с вашим текстом https://regex101.com/r/HSFSAT/3  Обратите внимание на модификатор `m` он заставляет `$` быть концом любой строки а не всего текста в целом

Comment: @Mike спасибо, то что нужно ! Хотел спросить есть у вас ссылка на ресурс где описывается более подробно про работу Regex ?

Comment: В википедии довольно много написано https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F  Еще можно взять главу про регулярки (5) из книги "Программирование на perl" (Кристиансен, Уолл) гипотетически можно найти в онлайне. Опустив из нее пару тем где то в конце, там возможности работающие только в перле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DevType.*?\s(\w+)$
```

Использовать с модификатором `m` (multiline) что бы $ был концом любой строки, а не всего текста.
Пример на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HSFSAT/3/)